# How to achieve the multitext search in modules of Sugar CRM

Tags: search, full-text-search, sugarcrm

I am using the Sugar CRM community version (6.5). Inside the module I want to do multi-text search for example Account name start with "Joel " and "John", the expected output is to get the Accounts have name with John/Joel, I have used wild card operator(AND / OR) but not getting the results.

1. Tried with wild card search (AND/OR operator) ends with no results.
2. Some changes in module layout of search

```
%Joel AND John%
%Joel & John%
%Joel% AND %John%
%Joel% & %John%
%Joel OR John%
%Joel |John%
%Joel% OR %John%
%Joel% | %John%
```

To get the list of accounts which contains name called Joel and John according to the wild card operator we used.

Answer (score 0):

Direct pass wildcard in search field.
PFB,

[image]

Comment: The above operation which you have done is similar to the "LIKE " operator but what I want to achieve is a Multi text search. Ex: Let's take some of the accounts have Insurance and Health inside it, How can I get the result of these (accounts which has both the keywords Insurance and Health)?